# Fill missing values in a column in File A with the matching column values from File B

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have 2 files; I want to replace the NAs from File A to a column in File B.

```
File A

ENSG00000134539 131.178876666595 8.17899671725794 0.855069805781827    9.56529708095531 1.12E-21 1.74E-20 KLRD1
ENSG00000135250 1133.42737699143 -1.12767591222818 0.117927787197502 -9.56242747385385 1.15E-21 1.78E-20 SRPK2
ENSG00000214870 103.556102419252 -2.15426846253205 0.225384371016956 -9.55819808095733 1.20E-21 1.86E-20 NA
ENSG00000136153 249.119544948009 -1.32395826295328 0.138571556732024 -9.55432914356018 1.24E-21 1.93E-20 LMO7

File B

ENSG00000214870 AC004540.5 103.556102419252
ENSG00000267121 CTD-2020K17.1 231.295616750853
ENSG00000254733 RP11-317J19.1 53.0097117074116
```

I want to match File A and File B on first column and replace the NAs in the last column of File A with the second column in File B.

I tried a lot of ways but since I am new to Linux I could not accomplish it.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]++;next} B[$7]==A[$2]' file1 file2

awk 'NR==FNR{ if (A[$1] in B[$1]) B[$7]==A[$2]}' file1 file2
```

What is wrong with my commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in a) && $NF=="NA"{$NF=a[$1]} 1' f2 f1
```

- `a[$1]=$2` use first column as key and save second column data as value
- `($1 in a) && $NF=="NA"` check if first column is a key in `a` array and if last column is `NA`

  - `$NF=a[$1]` change last column to value saved in `a` array
- `1` print input record contents
- `f2 f1` note the order of input files.. second file followed by first file

Comment: @Saad If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.